# TypeError: ecwidData.map is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, rest

This code below is to read data from an api, but it throws this error "TypeError: ecwidData.map is not a function".

> Note: I'm a beginner learning js and reactjs currently.

.
.
.

**page imports**

```
import axios from "axios";
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { Table } from "semantic-ui-react";
```

.............

**The Function code**

```
export default function Read() {
  let [ecwidData, setEcwidData] = useState([]);
  useEffect(() => {
    axios.get(
        'apiurl'
      )
      .then((response) => {
        setEcwidData(response.data);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        document.write(error);
      })
  }, [])
  return (
    <div>
      <Table singleLine>
        <Table.Header>
          <Table.Row>
            <Table.HeaderCell>ID</Table.HeaderCell>
            <Table.HeaderCell>Category</Table.HeaderCell>
            <Table.HeaderCell>Description</Table.HeaderCell>
            <Table.HeaderCell>URL</Table.HeaderCell>
            <Table.HeaderCell>Products count</Table.HeaderCell>
            <Table.HeaderCell>Enabled</Table.HeaderCell>
          </Table.Row>
        </Table.Header>

        <Table.Body>
          {ecwidData.map((data) => {
            return (
              <Table.Row>
                <Table.Cell>{data.id}</Table.Cell>
                <Table.Cell>{data.name}</Table.Cell>
                <Table.Cell>{data.description}</Table.Cell>
                <Table.Cell>{data.url}</Table.Cell>
                <Table.Cell>{data.productCount}</Table.Cell>
                <Table.Cell>{data.enabled}</Table.Cell>
              </Table.Row>
            );
          })}
        </Table.Body>
      </Table>
    </div>
  );
}
```

......
......
This is the api response from calling the api in the browser:
......
......

```
{
    "total": 58,
    "count": 58,
    "offset": 0,
    "limit": 100,
    "items": [
        {
            "id": 127443167,
            "parentId": 127443594,
            "orderBy": 10,
            "name": "Bathroom robe",
            "nameTranslated": {
                "ar": "Bathroom robe",
                "en": "",
                "fr": ""
            },
            "url": "",
            "productCount": 0,
            "description": "",
            "descriptionTranslated": {
                "ar": "",
                "en": "",
                "fr": ""
            },
            "enabled": true,
            "isSampleCategory": false
        }
... etc
```

Comment: Can you show us what `response.data` is?

Comment: you should check if response.data is an array

Comment: its a var to store the api response into data!

Comment: yes, i understand that. but if **response.data**  is not an array, then after running:
`.then((response) => {
        setEcwidData(response.data);
})`
**ecwidData** isn't array.

so, it will error
`ecwidData.map((data) => ...)`

Comment: check back the code i added the api response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should change:

```
<Table.Body>
  {ecwidData.map((data) => { return (
  <Table.Row>
    <Table.Cell>{data.id}</Table.Cell>
    <Table.Cell>{data.name}</Table.Cell>
    <Table.Cell>{data.description}</Table.Cell>
    <Table.Cell>{data.url}</Table.Cell>
    <Table.Cell>{data.productCount}</Table.Cell>
    <Table.Cell>{data.enabled}</Table.Cell>
  </Table.Row>
  ); })}
</Table.Body>
```

to

```
<Table.Body>
  {ecwidData?.items?.map((data) => { return (
  <Table.Row>
    <Table.Cell>{data.id}</Table.Cell>
    <Table.Cell>{data.name}</Table.Cell>
    <Table.Cell>{data.description}</Table.Cell>
    <Table.Cell>{data.url}</Table.Cell>
    <Table.Cell>{data.productCount}</Table.Cell>
    <Table.Cell>{data.enabled}</Table.Cell>
  </Table.Row>
  ); })}
</Table.Body>
```

Comment: Thanks it does the trick.

Answer (score 0):

I found a better solution by just accessing the nested object directly!

```
    <Table.Body>
  {ecwidData.map((data) => { return (
  <Table.Row>
    <Table.Cell>{data.items.id}</Table.Cell>
    <Table.Cell>{data.items.name}</Table.Cell>
    <Table.Cell>{data.items.description}</Table.Cell>
    <Table.Cell>{data.items.url}</Table.Cell>
    <Table.Cell>{data.items.productCount}</Table.Cell>
    <Table.Cell>{data.items.enabled}</Table.Cell>
  </Table.Row>
  ); })}
</Table.Body>
```